# creating a neon-glow with python numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to create a neon-effect w/ a source image. I have included three images, the source, my current attempt & a target. The program takes the image, finds the white-edges, & calculates the distance from each pixel to the nearest white-edge (these parts both work fine); from there, I am struggling to find the right saturation and value parameters to create the neon-glow.

From the target image, what I need to happen is basically for the saturation to be 0 on a white-edge, then to dramatically increase the further away it gets from an edge; for value, I need it to be 1 on a white-edge, then to dramatically decrease. I can't figure out the best way to manipulate distance_image (which holds each pixel's distance from the nearest white-edge) such as to achieve these two results with saturation and value.

```
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import binary_erosion
from scipy.spatial import KDTree

def find_closest_distance(img):
    white_pixel_points = np.array(np.where(img))
    tree = KDTree(white_pixel_points.T)
    img_meshgrid = np.array(np.meshgrid(np.arange(img.shape[0]),
                                        np.arange(img.shape[1]))).T
    distances, _ = tree.query(img_meshgrid)
    return distances

def find_edges(img):
    img_np = np.array(img)
    kernel = np.ones((3,3))
    return img_np - binary_erosion(img_np, kernel)*255

img = Image.open('a.png').convert('L')
edge_image = find_edges(img)
distance_image = find_closest_distance(edge_image)
max_dist = np.max(distance_image)
distance_image = distance_image / max_dist

hue = np.full(distance_image.shape, 0.44*180)
saturation = distance_image * 255
value = np.power(distance_image, 0.2)
value = 255 * (1 - value**2)

new_tups = np.dstack((hue, saturation, value)).astype('uint8')
new_tups = cv2.cvtColor(new_tups, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
new_img = Image.fromarray(new_tups, 'RGB').save('out.png')
```

The following images show the source data (left), the current result (middle), and the desired result (right).

[image: source]
[image: current]
[image: target]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I would do this with [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) instead. Convolving an image with a [Gaussian kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_filter) is a common way to [blur an image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur). You can do it in various ways, but maybe the easiest to use is [`scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter.html). Here's one way to implement all this, see if you like the result.

```py
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
import requests
import numpy as np

r = requests.get('https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhUQZ.png')
img = Image.open(BytesIO(r.content))
imarray = np.asarray(img)[..., 0] / 255
```

This is your first image, the white rectangles.

Now I'll make those outlines, do the blur, create the colour images, and combine them:

```py
from scipy.ndimage import binary_erosion
from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter

eroded = binary_erosion(imarray, iterations=3)

# Make the outlined rectangles.
outlines = imarray - eroded

# Convolve with a Gaussian to effect a blur.
blur = gaussian_filter(outlines, sigma=11)

# Make binary images into neon green.
neon_green_rgb = [0.224, 1.0, 0.0784]
outlines = outlines[:, :, None] * neon_green_rgb
blur = blur[:, :, None] * neon_green_rgb

# Combine the images and constrain to [0, 1].
blur_strength = 3
glow = np.clip(outlines + blur_strength*blur, 0, 1)
```

And look at it:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.imshow(glow)
```

[image: Glowing rectangle result]

You'll want to adjust the `sigma` of the Gaussian (its width), the colours, blur strength, and so on. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the input
- Convert to grayscale
- Threshold to binary
- Get edges of desired thickness using morphology gradient
- Invert the edges so black on white background
- Do distance transform
- Stretch to full dynamic range
- Invert
- Normalize to range 0 to 1 by dividing by the maximum value
- Attenuate using a power law to control distance roll-off (ramping)
- Create a color image of the size of the input and the desired color
- Multiply the attenuated image by the color image
- Save results

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import skimage.exposure

# read input
img = cv2.imread('rectangles.png')

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# do morphology gradient to get edges and invert so black edges on white background
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
edges = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_GRADIENT, kernel)
edges = 255 - edges

# get distance transform
dist = edges.copy()
distance = cv2.distanceTransform(dist, distanceType=cv2.DIST_L2, maskSize=3)
print(np.amin(distance), np.amax(distance))

# stretch to full dynamic range and convert to uint8 as 3 channels
stretch = skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(distance, in_range=('image'), out_range=(0,255))

# invert 
stretch = 255 - stretch
max_stretch = np.amax(stretch)

# normalize to range 0 to 1 by dividing by max_stretch
stretch = (stretch/max_stretch)

# attenuate with power law 
pow = 4
attenuate = np.power(stretch, pow)
attenuate = cv2.merge([attenuate,attenuate,attenuate])

# create a green image the size of the input
color_img = np.full_like(img, (0,255,0), dtype=np.float32)

# multiply the color image with the attenuated distance image
glow = (color_img * attenuate).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)

# save results
cv2.imwrite('rectangles_edges.png', edges)
cv2.imwrite('rectangles_stretch.png', (255*stretch).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8))
cv2.imwrite('rectangles_attenuate.png', (255*attenuate).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8))
cv2.imwrite('rectangles_glow.png', glow)

# view results
cv2.imshow("EDGES", edges)
cv2.imshow("STRETCH", stretch)
cv2.imshow("ATTENUATE", attenuate)
cv2.imshow("RESULT", glow)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Edges (inverted):

[image]

Stretched Distance Transform:

[image]

Attenuated Distance Transform:

[image]

Glow Result:

[image]